# pyinstaller error with pyqt5. cannot run the distribution file. loading two sets of Qt binaries?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, pyinstaller

python 3.7
macos 10.14.5
anaconda environment

I have written a simple python code using pyqt5 that works very nicely from the command line. I want to make it into an app so others can use it (who don't have python etc). Pyinstaller looked like the way to go.
I followed instructions on numerous websites, and always get the same result: it doesn't run.

I have searched numerous sites including stackoverflow for how to deal with this error, but I came up blank. I see that other people have had this error, but I still do not understand why or how to fix it. I am self-taught and not extremely advanced. The github forums are beyond me because they don't explain enough or give good directions.

```
pyinstaller --name="[my app]" --console  [my file].py
```

Building proceeds successfully, and I get a distribution file in the newly created dist directory. But, instead of running, the app blinks and closes immediately.
to see what was happening, I created a unwindowed distribution and got this error:

> objc[4607]: Class RunLoopModeTracker is implemented in both
>   /Users/.../dist/[my app]/libQt5Core.5.dylib (0x1085b2a80) and
>   /Users/.../anaconda3/envs/[my env]/lib/libQt5Core.5.9.7.dylib
>   (0x10dd79a80). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
>
> objc[4607]: Class NotificationReceiver is implemented in both
>   /Users/.../dist/[my app]/libQt5Widgets.5.dylib (0x107d401b8) and
>   /Users/.../anaconda3/envs/[my env]/lib/libQt5Widgets.5.9.7.dylib
>   (0x10d5071b8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
>
> QObject::moveToThread: Current thread (0x7fae6760a8c0) is not the
>   object's thread (0x7fae674d6f10).
>
> Cannot move to target thread (0x7fae6760a8c0)
>
> You might be loading two sets of Qt binaries into the same process.
>   Check that all plugins are compiled against the right Qt binaries.
>   Export DYLD_PRINT_LIBRARIES=1 and check that only one set of binaries
>   are being loaded.
>
> This application failed to start because it could not find or load the
>   Qt platform plugin "cocoa" in "".
>
> Available platform plugins are: cocoa, minimal, offscreen.

I can see that there is a conflict because Qt seems to be in 2 places. I think I need to know I can force pyinstaller to use the correct one during the build. Is that correct and does anyone know how to do that?

Comment: I posted my solution here: stackoverflow.com/a/72863910/3844056 . I will posit that `libQt5Core` brought by PyInstaller from anaconda3 is the cause of the conflict. I was able to work around this by NOT using anaconda with PyInstaller to package my Qt app.